# Reading file as ndarray in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, genfromtxt

I want to read file as ndarray with variable number of rows and 6 columns and the first row is the names of columns. 
I used this

```
data = np.genfromtxt('attack-traffic.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',', names=True)
```

but when I

```
print data.shape
```

It gives me

```
(1680,)
```

how can I do it to read 6 columns?

Comment: By passing in `names=True`, you're creating a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html). Your 1680 records will each have 6 fields.

Comment: @OliverW. Then why the shape doesn't give me (1680,6)??  I'm new with Numpy

Answer (score 0):

By passing in `names=True` to [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), you're creating a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.rec.html). Your 1680 records will each have 6 fields.

Example:

```
oliver@armstrong:/tmp$ cat sto.txt 
id,num
1,1.2
2,2.4
oliver@armstrong:/tmp$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.genfromtxt('/tmp/sto.txt', names=True, delimiter=',')
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a[0]  # each record has 2 fields
(1.0, 1.2)
>>> a[0].dtype
dtype([('id', '<f8'), ('num', '<f8')])
>>> a[0]['num']
1.2
```

You can also access just those fields, and it will tell you how many elements there are per field:

```
>>> a['num'].shape
(2,)
>>> a['num']
array([ 1.2,  2.4])
```

Definitely read the documentation on structured arrays if you want to know more. The provided link is full of good examples.

If you know a priori that all elements in that file are floats (and by passing `dtype=float`, you indicate that you know), you could convert the structured array to a normal `ndarray`:

```
>>> a = np.genfromtxt('/tmp/sto.txt', names=True, delimiter=',', dtype=float) # added `dtype=float` in the call
>>> b = a.view(np.float64).reshape(a.shape[0], -1)
>>> b
array([[ 1. ,  1.2],
       [ 2. ,  2.4]])
```

Note that this returns a *view*, so any change you make to `a` will be reflected in `b` and vice versa.

Comment: Ok got it. but why when I calling this   plt.plot(data[:,0],data[:,1] ,'ob',alpha=0.2, markersize=4) it gives me IndexError: too many indices

Comment: @EmanBanysalameh When you have a structured array, you can simply call the columns by passing the names (that were obtained from the file). Just call `plt.plot(data['field1'], data['field2'])` where `field1` and `field2` are the names of the columns in the file. In my example, I would have used `plt.plot(a['id'], a['num'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Try pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('attack-traffic.csv')
print df.columns
print df.head()
```

Then check with Numpy..

```
import numpy as np
data = np.genfromtxt('attack-traffic.csv', dtype=float, delimiter=',')
```

Try: `dtype=str`